# What is one word to describe someone who doesn't care about anything?

Tags: single-word-requests, descriptive-grammar

My friend says she wants me to describe her in one word and I think she does not care about anything most of the time. So I'm looking for a word that describes that.

Comment: How about *indifferent*?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a noun for that. But I can think of some adjectives:

> ***Apathetic*** derived from [ODO](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/apathetic)
>
> Which not interested or concerned. Having or showing little or no emotion.

The synonym may be:

> ***Unfeeling***
>
> Which means lacking physical sensation or sensitivity.

Or:

> ***Indifferent***
>
> Which means having no particular interest or sympathy; unconcerned.

Answer (score 0):

**Carefree** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/carefree)

> *adjective* having no worries or problems : free from care
>
> *"She has a carefree attitude toward life."*
> *"They spent a carefree day at the lake."*

**Free spirit** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/free%20spirit)

> *noun* a person who thinks and acts in a free way without worrying about normal social rules
>
> *"Their daughter is a real free spirit."*